# How to display ROR 5 ActiveRecord pluck as String in html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, pluck

In html.erb I have:

```
<%= ContactDescribe.where(["contact_describe_id = ?", "12"]).limit(1).pluck(:borrower_or_lender_text)  %>
```

The field is retrieved successfully.  But returns an array element.  I need to learn how to convert that element to a string.

Comment: don't query complex stuff in views

Comment: This is not a bad question and shouldn't be downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Deepak's answer, you can also convert the `Array` into a "Sentence" String

```
<%= ContactDescribe.where(contact_describe_id: 12).limit(1).pluck(:borrower_or_lender_text).to_sentence %>
```

### Recommendation:

- As pointed out by TheChamp, it is best practice to already "prepare" the values needed in the views as instance variables from the controller. See my recommended refactor

  ```
  # controller
  def YOUR_ACTION_NAME
    @contact_describe = ContactDescribe.where(contact_describe_id: 12).first
  end

  # view
  <%= @contact_describe.borrower_or_lender_text %>
  ```

**Note:** you won't even need pluck anymore unless you have other reasons why you want `limit(1)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Okay this is new to me.  In the the controller, show view I only define the parent record.  Can I also define additional values like @contact_describe?

Comment: @emm, yes "normally", feel free to add instance_variables as much as you want in the controller. The instance_variables normally are Record objects / any complicated stuff that needs to be put into a "variable" to be shown on the views. However, don't get too carried away and assign every possible code in the view as instance variables! :) (case in point: don' t do the following in the controller! `@contact_describe_borrower_or_lender_text = ContactDescribe.where(contact_describe_id: 12).first.borrower_or_lender_text` as you might need to reuse `@contact_describe` in the views down the road .

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that `where` returns a collection - something similar to an array, just in ActiveRecord - no matter what limit you set on it. To retrieve the information you would use `.first` or `[0]` since you always only return one object.

**But**, since you are looking for a specific `ContactDescribe` object. **Do this instead:**

```
ContactDescribe.find_by(contact_describe_id: 12).borrower_or_lender
```

---

Additionally there two things you should improve in your code.

1: Logic should go into the controller or the model. A view is solely here to show objects.

2: What is up with the `contact_describe_id` field? Why not call it `id`. It seems redundant. Isn't `user.id` more convenient than `user.user_id`?

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of `join`

```
<%= ContactDescribe.where(contact_describe_id: 12).limit(1).pluck(:borrower_or_lender_text).join(',')  %>
```

Comment: That's a different part

Comment: The main question is different and this answer solves the main question

Comment: @TheCha͢mp the policy of SO is [Be Nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). If you don't agree with this answer, *then downvote*, that's what they are for. There is no need for comments like that and it just wastes everyone's time. DeepakMahakale is under no obligation to help *anyone*.

Comment: ye I guess I got too emotional..., sorry Deepak

Comment: Thanks.  In a different context this suggestion may be useful.  Or suggested join ridiculous, hence The Champ comments?

Comment: yes in a different context `join()` is very useful, I overreacted because I felt he should address other issues with your code as well